# When I use jquery count body's height,the absolute position element'height wouldn't be include?

Tags: html, css, height, position, absolute

Hello all，I'm a junior on html,I have a question about css position :

first here is my demo html code

```
<div id="test-header"></div>
<div id="test-content"></div>
<input type="button" value="body">
```

I set the "test-content" `position: absolute`,the "test-header" in default

but when I use $("body").height() to get the body's height,it only alert the "test-header"'s height ……

So why count would not include the abasolute element's height?

How can I solve this problem ?

[here is my online case](http://jsfiddle.net/xXUfA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct result, when you absolutely position an element it's taken out of the flow of the `document`, and doesn't occupy any space inside it's parent...which is why `<body>` doesn't account for the size it takes up.

Comment: I get it ……But how can I count body's height with include absolute element's height at the same time ?

Comment: @hh54188 - Let's say you had 20 absolutely positioned elements overlapping, all over the place...what should the overall dimensions be?  You see how this isn't an easy question once you think about the scenarios? :)

Comment: beaten again, nice one nick :) @hh54118, if you want to see what nick is talking about add a border to the body element, you will notice test-content and the input button are outside the border :)

Comment: thank you very much ,the example you provide is very good ,I never consider the scenarios before ,just think all ordered in default